# Transformando um datatable em array com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-charts

Tenho como saida uma string com o seguinte formato.

```
[["link"],["<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='452' height='272' src='http://www2.camara.leg.br/camaranoticias/tv/embedAoVivo.html?width=450&height=253'  frameborder='0'></iframe>"]]
```

Ela representa um datatable. Eu quero acessar o segundo elemento. Se possível como array em jquery. Alguém poderia dar uma dica?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery é Javascript, logo você pode acessar normalmente via []

```
var x = [["link"],["<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='452' height='272' src='http://www2.camara.leg.br/camaranoticias/tv/embedAoVivo.html?width=450&height=253'  frameborder='0'></iframe>"]];

alert(x[0]);
alert(x[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8zzgrr5/